# Firebase query DataSnapshot val() returning null

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase structure is below

```
  {
  "Test1 Lab" : {
    "Equipment" : "3-D printer",
    "Hours" : "7AM-6PM",
    "Location" : "Library",
    "Name" : "Digital Lab"
  },
  "Test2 Lab" : {
    "Equipment" : "Oculus",
    "Hours" : "7AM-6PM",
    "Location" : "Hall",
    "Name" : "Test Lab"
  }
}
```

The top level is called "makerspace". I am trying to get the Name, Equipment, and Hours of the item where the Location is "Library" I ran the code:

```
var red = database.ref('makerspace');
    return red.orderByChild('Location').equalTo("Library").once('value').then(function(snapshot){
            console.log(snapshot.child("makerspace").child("Name").key);
    });
```

And I get "Name". However, when I change .key to .val(), I should expect to get "Digital Lab", but I get null. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Your `snapshot` contain values under `makerspace` node. then `snapshot.child("makerspace")` doesn't make any sense. try `snapshot.child("Name").val()`

Comment: using snapshot.child("Name").val() gives me null

Comment: i think you need a `forEach` loop to fetch data from `snapshot`

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot is already on the `makerspace` node, so it should be:

```
var red = database.ref('makerspace');
return red.orderByChild('Location').equalTo("Library").once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.child("Name").val());
});
```

Comment: I tried this, and It printed out null. Snapshot.key gives makerspace.

Comment: try `console.log(snapshot,val())` in the callback to see what info is in the snapshot.

Comment: console.log(snapshot.val()) returned null

Comment: Seems like there's no data with those conditions, `Location === Library'.

Comment: But there should be, the Json above is the exact one i'm using.

Comment: Is the root of the project's database makerspace? Or is there any other node before that one?

Comment: When I export the JSON from firebase, it shows the structure above. When I look at the project structure in firebase though, it shows makerspace as a parent of both Test1 Lab and Test2 Lab.

Comment: try `database.ref('makerspace').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val());
});`

Comment: Prints null again

Comment: Then the node `nakerspace` is not defined. Are you sure the name is thatone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var red = database.ref('makerspace');
return red.orderByChild('Location').equalTo("Library").once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
       console.log(data.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I got this error: (index):104 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of null

Comment: Remove this `.orderByChild('Location').equalTo("Library")` and check it working or not

Comment: Still nothing got printed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to access snapshot data like this,

```
red.orderByChild('Location').equalTo("Library").once('value').then(function(snapshot){
       console.log(snapshot.val());   <==========
       // result would be
{ "Test1 Lab" : { "Equipment" : "3-D printer","Hours" : "7AM-6PM","Location" : "Library","Name" : "Digital Lab" } }
        }
```

To get properties you can do,

```
       snapshot.val()['Test1 Lab']['Name'] or snapshot.val()['Test1 Lab'].Name
       snapshot.val()['Test1 Lab']['Hours']
```

Now you can get 'Test1 Lab' using Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]

snapshot.val() is like JSON Object, so just access its properties like you did for objects. No need to use child() method to access data.